# php-fpm 7.2: $pool variable is not valid anymore?

Tags: php

Back in PHP5, we could do something like

/etc/php5/fpm/common.conf

```
user = $pool
group = $pool
...
```

Then I can include it in other conf files.
Example:

/etc/php5/fpm/www.conf

```
[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
include = /etc/php5/fpm/common.conf
```

However, in php7.2 I get the following error

```
Starting php-fpm-7.2: ERROR: [/etc/php-fpm-7.2.d/common.conf:1] unknown entry 'user'
ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php-fpm-7.2.d/common.conf from /etc/php-fpm.conf at line 1
ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php-fpm.conf'
ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

The $pool variable is not valid anymore.

Any idea what is the alternative?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pool` instead of `$pool`? I don't thing variables like this work in the conf files, since it's a different language syntax.

Comment: @aynber it used to work in php5. see https://serverfault.com/questions/741325/include-common-configuration-in-several-php5-fpm-pools for example

Comment: Ah, interesting. I have a feeling from the error message that it's more the `user` it doesn't like than the `$pool`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was that I put common.conf inside conf dir.

Now I moved it under includes

```
[testme1]
include = /etc/php-fpm-7.2.d/includes/common.conf
```

And I can use $pool inside it.

My bad.